# Two buttons changing class like radio buttons but only one at the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

```js
$('#axe, #saw').click(function(e) {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  if (id == 'axe') {
    $(this).toggleClass('as-in-one as-one');
  } else if (id == 'saw') {
    $(this).toggleClass('as-in-two as-two');
  }

})
```

```css
.as-in-one {
  color: red;
}

.as-one {
  color: blue;
}

.as-in-two {
  color: red;
}

.as-two {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='axe' class='axe as-in-one'>AXE</button>
<button id='saw' class='saw as-in-two'>SAW</button>
```

In my code here I want to be able to change only one button's class, from `red` to `blue`, But if i clicked on another button, The first button turns to the default class `red` if it was `blue` and the other be toggled to `blue` And vice versa.

Comment: what think about varibale. If you click and change button to blue set it to global variable and next click check if blue then set blue.

Comment: *"...but only one at the time"* Er, that's how radio buttons work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not how I'd like to do - but there you go! When `axe` is clicked, add the `as-in-two` class and remove the `as-two` class, and when `saw` is clicked, add the `as-in-one` class and remove the `as-one` class.

See demo below:

```js
$('#axe, #saw').click(function(e) {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  if (id == 'axe') {
    $(this).toggleClass('as-in-one as-one');
    $('#saw').addClass('as-in-two');
    $('#saw').removeClass('as-two');
  } else if (id == 'saw') {
    $(this).toggleClass('as-in-two as-two');
    $('#axe').addClass('as-in-one');
    $('#axe').removeClass('as-one');
  }

})
```

```css
.as-in-one {
  color: red;
}

.as-one {
  color: blue;
}

.as-in-two {
  color: red;
}

.as-two {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='axe' class='axe as-in-one'>AXE</button>
<button id='saw' class='saw as-in-two'>SAW</button>
```

Better to use a single `red` and `blue` class:

```js
$('.as-in-one').click(function(e) {
   $('.as-in-one').not(this).removeClass('as-one');
   $(this).toggleClass('as-one');
})
```

```css
.as-in-one {
  color: red;
}
.as-in-one.as-one {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='axe' class='as-in-one'>AXE</button>
<button id='saw' class='as-in-one'>SAW</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need separate classes for the buttons, and if you use the same classes on them, it makes it easier: Just select the "other" button and reset its state:

```js
$('#axe, #saw').click(function(e) {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  var other = $(id == 'axe' ? '#saw' : '#axe');
  $(this).toggleClass('as-in as');
  other.removeClass("as").addClass("as-in");
});
```

```css
.as-in {
  color: red;
}

.as {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='axe' class='axe as-in'>AXE</button>
<button id='saw' class='saw as-in'>SAW</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You were looking for some thing like this.

```js
$('#axe, #saw').click(function(e) {
  if(!$(this).hasClass('as')){
    $(this).toggleClass('as');
    $(this).siblings().not(this).removeClass('as');
  }
})
```

```css
.as-in {
  color: red;
}

.as {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='axe' class='axe as-in'>AXE</button>
<button id='saw' class='saw as-in'>SAW</button>
```